# Error in association of two models (AssociationTypeMismatch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to choose an author when creating a post. I have a Post and Author model. In the author's model, I prescribed `has_many :posts`, and in the Post model `belongs_to :author`. In the form view, created a list of authors `<%= form.select(:author, Author.all.collect {|p| [ p.first_name] }) %>` In the post controller I prescribed:

```rb
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :picture, :author)
    end
```

However, when creating a post I get an error `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in PostsController#create` `Author(#70151313190260) expected, got "AuthorName" which is an instance of String(#47111701634520)`

UPD.
All that i'm getting:

```
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2019-11-17 22:39:33 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"o8rcT1Jo/seI+zs+CRa6Ro3Wu14oz7OJ9zE0OLgtjkWVAOVJ05VeRM17Je27STO0/pV9Sdrn5XinOANv6VCwlA==", "post"=>{"author"=>"4", "title"=>"TitleName", "content"=>"SomeContent"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 842)



ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Author(#69935628031800) expected, got "4" which is an instance of String(#47189092695520)):

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

def create in post_controller:

```rb
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

#before action
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the id when constructing the select tag.

Try:

```
<%= form.select :author, Author.pluck(:id, :first_name) %>
```

Which creates a selector where the value is the author `id` and the text is the author `first_name`.

As stated also by @Chiperific in the comments, you need to update your `post_params` to allow an `author_id` instead of an `author`.

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: Can you add the whole you're getting and the lines of code where it's produced?

Comment: Once you do what @SebastianPalma suggests, then you have to change your params to this: `params.require(:post).permit(:name, :title, :content, :picture, :author_id)`

Comment: I did so, but now instead of the names of the authors, their id is listed.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your decision helped me, thanks. Just earlier, when creating a post, the names of the authors were displayed in the list, and it was convenient to choose. And right now instead of them their id.